# Problem working with NSMutableArray to store objects other than just strings in UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, nsmutablearray, uitableview

I am a novice using iPhone SDK and Objective C. I am facing a stupid issue with the `NSMutableArray` object.

I have a `Team` class and a `Player` class. `Team` class has an `NSMutableArray` object that holds the `Player` objects. `Team` class is initialized with `initWithTitle:(NSString*)title` constructor. `Player` has `Name` property.

Now, I have a simple Navigation based application with a `UITableViewController` that shows a row with  Add Player. When this row is selected, it opens a `UIViewController` that has a textField in which user can enter new player name (ex.Player1). When clicked on back button, row with new player name should appear above the Add Player row. After adding the second player (eg.Player2), the rows  should look like:

Player1

Player2

Add Player

I am using `PlayerUpdatedDelegate` with method
`-(void)PlayerUpdated:(NSString*)playerName;` to transfer new player name back to `UITableViewController` when back button is clicked. In this method I create a new `Player` object and add to `Team` using `[team.players addObject:player];`

The problem that I am facing is after entering player's name and clicking on back button, the application crashes when I am trying to access the player's name in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method like below:

```
if (indexPath.row < [team.players count]) {
    Player *player = [team.players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell textLabel].text = [player name]; // This is the line that fails........
    [player autorelease];
}
else {
    [cell textLabel].text = @"Add New Player";
}

return cell;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks. If you want to take a look at the simple app, I have uploaded it to:  http://www.box.net/shared/y4ct7carfr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. When I was retrieving the `Player` object from the `NSMutableArray`, I did not cast it to `Player`. When I cast it, it works. So that solves it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use `self` with property, synthesize. When you write

```
title = teamTitle;
```

retain count of title will not increase and the program will also crash in Team class dealloc, because you release title whose retain count is 0. Correct tose errors like this

```
self.title = teamTitle;
```

Correct relevant codes first and retry.
**Edit**

In `-(void) setPlayerName:(NSString *)playerName` 
try

```
self.name = playerName;
```

Comment: @EEE: You are right about team.title; but I am not facing any problem with team.title. It is the player name that I am having problem with when I retrieve it from the players object in team.

Comment: Nope.. that doesnt help either... :(

Comment: I think you must should use tempPlayer = [player retain] instead of tempPlayer = player in RootviewContr, and in other relevant places.

Comment: Thanks EEE for your efforts. Please see my answer.